# How long does it take a ship to travel from Earth to Oasis?

Tags: tv, oasis

In Amazon's original series, *Oasis*, the passengers on the ship transporting them "across the galaxy" to the Oasis colony are put into an drug-induced coma for the duration of the journey, which implies a long voyage. Is there any indication on how long the trip takes?

I realize only the pilot episode has been released so far (as of July 2017) and information may be scarce at this point. I ask this question on the off chance that *Oasis* might be based on a book with more details or that someone from the show has addressed this in an interview.

Comment: It is indeed based on a novel: [The Book of Strange New Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Of_Strange_New_Things), by [Michael Faber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Faber)

Comment: @Gnemlock - I don't think I have enough rep points to make tags. And if I do, I don't know how using the SE app on my phone which I use exclusively. Thanks to Gallifreyan for setting one up.

Comment: I have been told you need rep for tags,but I also see 1rep users make them, so I know you dont. You cant make them on the phone, however; I had the same problem :P

Answer (score 1):

In the source novel ([*The Book of Strange New Things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_Of_Strange_New_Things) by Michael Faber), the outward journey takes around thirty days. It's not clear whether this is the same in the TV movie (given how many other changes that were made), but there's really no good reason to assume that this was altered.

> He closed the book. His hands were trembling. **He knew that there was quite a decent chance that he would die in the next thirty days**, or that, even if he survived the journey, he would never return.
>
> ...
>
> The cannula was in his vein; the IV drip was activated; the
> translucent substance moved into him. He thought he might vomit from
> the sheer ghastliness of it. They ought to have given him a sedative
> or something. **He wondered if his three fellow travelers were braver
> than him. They were nestled in identical cribs, elsewhere in the
> building, but he couldn’t see them. He would meet them in a month from
> now, when he woke up.**

Note that in the original book, travel between Earth and Oasis was sufficiently commonplace that several of the characters had made *multiple* trips to and from the planet in the previous years whereas in the film it's more of a *"one way trip, and you might be able to return to Earth in a few decades time"* deal.

Comment: Given the heavy-handedness of the whole thing, I'm astounded that it didn't take forty days and forty nights to travel.